# Show spinner til data gets reflected in DOM-angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filter

I'm having huge data set displayed in table (5000 rows).
I'm trying to filter data by having column filter and when applying the same I've kept a spinner to show that filter operation is in progress

But since the action is so quick in javascript the boolean variable that I used as flag to check if data is filtered/not filtered gets changed quickly

However it takes around 2 seconds to reflect the fresh data into the DOM. I want to show spinner during this DOM binding time.

#### HTML:

```
 <div *ngIf="isFilterClicked" class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;color: #165cb9;height: 440px;padding-top:100px">
                <px-spinner size="100">
                </px-spinner>
            </div>
        <div *ngFor="let product of products"> 
        </div>
```

#### Javascript

```
this.initialProducts=this.products; //initialize 

filterTable(filterData) {
    this.isFilterClicked = true;
    const result = this.initialProducts.filter(function (o1) {
        return o1.id === filterData.id; // return the ones with equal id
    });
});             
this.products= result ;
this.isFilterClicked = false;
}
```

Comment: You are mixing angular and angularjs syntax in template?

Comment: @AJT_82 Thanks for pointing out.I've updated template syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you set the boolean varibale to flase when ngFor finishes

```
<div *ngIf="isFilterClicked" class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;color: #165cb9;height: 440px;padding-top:100px">
  Loading data....
</div>
<button (click)="filterEvenProducts()">Filter Even</button>
<button (click)="filterOddProducts()">Filter Odd</button>
<div #allProducts *ngFor="let product of products;">
  {{product}}
</div>
```

**component**

```
export class ProductComponent implements AfterViewInit {

initialProducts = [];
products = [];
isFilterClicked = false;

@ViewChildren('allProducts') things: QueryList<any>;

constructor() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      this.initialProducts.push(`Product ${i}`);
      this.products = this.initialProducts;
    }
  }

filterEvenProducts() {
    this.isFilterClicked = true;
    this.products = this.initialProducts.filter((product, index) => (index % 2) === 0);
  }

  filterOddProducts() {
    this.isFilterClicked = true;
    this.products = this.initialProducts.filter((product, index) => (index % 2) !== 0);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.things.changes.subscribe(t => {
      // to avoid error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.isFilterClicked = false;
      }, 500);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Is last = last is the same as we put to get index like let last = index?

Comment: @forgottofly yes you are correct!! when index is last call the method to stop spinner. let first = first; let last = last

Comment: Thanks Pratap.So should I use isLast method inside filterTable function ?

Comment: please find the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/xmlNqlGgzLZTut2gh1ea?p=preview Please let me know if this implementation is correct.

Comment: No Pratap. Can you please update plunker if possible. Thanks

Comment: @forgottofly updated answer and fiddle please check https://plnkr.co/edit/KKhjOnfPHHJu9NbFZJHc?p=preview

Comment: @forgottofly glad I was able to help you!!